# how can we send data from first activity to second activity and second activity to first activity bu using intent

Tags: android

Hi I am getting the problem to send the data from second activity to first activity

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setClass(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "this is second activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
String name=ed1.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("ok",name);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
startActivity(i);
```

how can we recive the data on first activity

Comment: What problem u are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, define a variable in you first activity like this (100 is just random, pick whatever you want):

```
private static final int SECOND_ACTIVITY = 100;
```

then in your first activity you start the second activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY);
```

also override onActivityResult in your first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String foo = data.getStringExtra("foo");
        }
    }
}
```

when you finish your second activity put you data, like this:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("foo", "bar");
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example for getting data from second activity.

```
//First activity
private static final int PLAY_GAME = 1010;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLAY_GAME && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String getData = data.getExtras().getString("returnStr");

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}





//second activity
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("returnStr", data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
```